# Regex evaluate string and inner strings in quotes for balance and length

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I want some regular expression to evaluate an entire string to ensure all inner strings are surrounded in quotes and are under a certain length (under 5 characters).

For Example (whole string in bold including spaces):

**"hi"** I want a match

**"goodbye"** I don't want to match, as the word **goodbye** is overlength

**"hoe" "hi hi"** I want to match, as all words are quoted and within length

**"hi" "hi hi" "hi hoe"** I don't want to match, as the sentence **hi hoe** is overlength

**"hi" "hi" hi** I don't want to match, as **hi** is unquoted

**"hi" "hi" "hi** I don't want to match, as **"hi** isn't completely quoted

**"hoe" "hoe" "hi "hoe"** I don't want to match, as **"hi** isn't completely quoted

Comment: What is not working in your attempt?

Comment: I ashamedly couldn't get my regex to evaluate the entire '^(\"[\w ]{,5}\" )+' worked as in evaluating the strings but when I added a '$' it failed to evaluate the whole string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to match full lines (`^...$`) where you have words in quotes (`\"[\w ]{,5}\"`) separated by spaces, except for the last one (`(?: |$)+`) any number of times, you can use:

```
^(?:\"[\w ]{,5}\"(?: |$)+)+$
```

[demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ET4i8U/4)

Edit: don't forget the multiline flag though.

Answer (score 1):

This could work

```
^((?:\"[\w\s]{1,5}\")(?:(?:\s+?\"[\w\s]{1,5}\")+)?)$
```

It basicaly evaluates string of 1 to 5 characters, delimited by " and allows more than one of those strings to repeat themselves, preceded by a space. Since it's bound by the begining and end of line, it would exclude entry that don't only countain such entries.